# Binary Subtraction - Extra Digit?

Tags: math, binary

Just messing around with Binary Subtraction using **two's complement** but I would like something explained.

To perform `11 - 9` I first convert the 9 to a negative number by changing the 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's and then add 1. Then I add the negative number so it becomes `11 +(-9)`

**Binary**

```
 00001011
+11110111
---------
100000010
```

As I understand it, I just disregard the MSB so it becomes:

```
00000010
```

Why is it the case that I can drop the MSB?

Comment: So that you don't get a 9-bit result (on a given CPU architecture, it is typically 17 or 33 or 65 instead of 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you effectively added it first.

The invert/add one combo is equivalent to subtracting from a constant "one larger than allowed":

```
100000000
 00001001
---------  -
 11110111
```

So you have changed `11 - 9` to `11 + (256 - 9)`, which you can write as `11 - 9 + 256` to make it even clearer that you added that "extra bit" yourself in order to do the math, so now you have to drop it to get the result of the original expression.